# What is the alternate option of memcached's replace() method in cakephp 3?

Tags: php, cakephp, memcached, cakephp-3.0

There is a `replace()` method of `memcached` class which I have used in core php. But now I want to use it in **cakephp 3**. I have configured cakephp 3 cache with memcached engine. But I can't use/call replace method. So what is the alternate option to use replace in cakephp 3. And if it is possible to use `replace()` in cakephp 3 then it will be much better than to use any alternate.